# Connecting to CentOS 7.9 with SSH error Permission Denied

Tags: ssh, centos, centos7

i try to connect to my Linux centOS server with Root user on port 22 with this command:

```
ssh -p 22 root@ip
```

but connection return this error:

```
root@ip: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you must change permissions on your server machine with this command:

```
chmod 700 /root/.ssh
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

then edit in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config to this:

```
sudo sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config;
sudo sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config;
```

Run:

```
systemctl stop sshd.service
```

and Run:

```
systemctl enable sshd.service
```

then Run:

```
systemctl start sshd.service
```

after that:

```
systemctl status sshd.service
```

and check the output. If everything goes well you should have ssh services every time you boot from now on.